# Option to make pen more visible on the screen in xournal

Tags: xournal

When using xournal the point where the pen is on the screen is sometimes very small (depending on the screen and resolution), so that I have to draw and erase something just to find the point on the screen. Is there any option which visually makes the position of the pen more visible on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select *Options* -> *Pencil Cursor* (as of [v. 0.4.8](https://github.com/dmgerman/xournal/blob/master/ChangeLog)).

Answer (score 3):

For version 1.1.0:

Edit -> Preferences -> View -> Cursor -> Cursor icon for pen -> Big pen icon.

But when activating the highlighting (same configuration window), the dot already increased a lot in size (no need to make it a Big pen anymore). If highlighting is disabled, I barely see the dot on my 4k screen (it is a really small dot). I usually only notice where it is, after starting my drawing.